# Sublime and coding-standards (coding-style): where should I begin?

Tags: coding-style, sublimetext2

I want to be able to define my own coding-standards (= coding-standards of the company).

If I execute auto-indent (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) should then run my own coding-standards.

Where to do it best in Sublime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CodeFormatter

Pre-Conditions:

- install php-pear (if not already installed)
- install phpbeautifier

Comment: yeah, it works better as phptidy. The shortcut CTRL+ALT+f is OK too.. I can also modify setting.. Very good, thank you!